# Javascript sort is not working on iOS and in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

im sorting items by date...

On Chrome its working great but on iOS or in Safari sorting its not working...

```
<script>
    function sortDates(b, a)
{
    return new Date(b).getTime() - new Date(a).getTime();
}

var dates = [];
var _old;

$('.sort').each(function(){
    _old = $(this).parent();
    dates.push($(this).data('date'));
});

var sorted = dates.sort(sortDates);
var _new = $('<div class="row" id="sort">').insertBefore(_old);

$.each(sorted,function(i,val){
    $('.sort[data-date="' + val + '"]').appendTo(_new);
});

_old.remove();
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Not working"? Isn't it sorting at all? Is it sorting it wrong? Does it throw an error?

Comment: Confirm the data format in the *dates* array, it may be caused by the time zone format, for example, you can try to print the following results in *Safari* and *Chrome*
`console.log(new Date("2022-07-06T20:00:00.000+04:00"));`
`console.log(new Date("2022-07-06T20:00:00.000+0400"));`